# What is the name of Master Shifu in the Chinese dub of Kung Fu Panda?

Tags: character, kung-fu-panda

*Master Shifu* is a supporting character in the *Kung Fu Panda* (franchise). But seeing as to how his name is something of a *tautonym* (*shifu* means *master* in Mandarin), what is used for his name in the Chinese dub?

Answer (score 3):

In the [Chinese dub](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%9F%E5%A4%AB%E7%86%8A%E7%8C%AB#%E9%85%8D%E9%9F%B3%E5%93%A1) he is called 功夫大師 (Kung-fu Dàshī).

大师 (*dàshī* lit. "great master") is another term for "master" in a martial arts context in China. It shares the character 师 with 师傅 / 师父 (*shīfù*).

Answer (score -1):

Most probably Sifu because their meaning is same.

> Sifu (Cantonese Chinese) or shifu (Mandarin Chinese) (or shih-fu) is
>   the identical pronunciation of two Chinese terms for a master. - (Source - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sifu))

But in [Dustin Hoffman's Chinese Wikipedia page](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BE%BE%E6%96%AF%E6%B1%80%C2%B7%E9%9C%8D%E5%A4%AB%E6%9B%BC), he is listed as 师傅 (Master).

Comment: I can understand if the dub uses just _Shifu_ rather than _Master_ Shifu. But _Master Shifu_ sounds unlikely to me. How about all the other [_masters_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kung_Fu_Panda_characters)?

Comment: @coleopterist ... Maybe he's the master of masters?

Comment: If you copy/paste "师傅" from that page (written right above "Master Shifu") using [Google translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E5%B8%88%E5%82%85), you get just "Master".

Comment: @VedranŠego correction done.

Comment: @AnkitSharma you're simplifying the Chinese language too much. There's also Simplified and Traditional Chinese. And also, Cantonese Chinese is used primarily in Hong Kong, so I don't know why you're assuming that its pronunciation of "Master" will be used in Chinese films.